# Why I can't use List.Add() on Parallel.For or Parallel.Foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, plinq

This is my code :

```
Parallel.ForEach(Students, item =>
{
   StudentModel studentModel = new StudentModel(item);

   // Maybe he/she has alot of name
   foreach (var words in studentModel.StudentNames.Split(','))
   {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(words))
                return;

        string tempWords = words.Trim();
        // add it to student names list
        STUDENT_NAMES.Where(x => x.SearchWords == tempWords).FirstOrDefault().student.Add(studentModel);


     }
     // add it to student list
     STUDENT_MODELS.Add(studentModel);
});
```

What I want to do is, I get the student list. convert it to student model, get student names(because one student has a lot names), then I add the names to names list, that's because maybe later I need get same name students and do some thing.....
finally add student to student models list.

The problem happening on :

```
STUDENT_NAMES.Where(x => x.SearchWords == tempWords).FirstOrDefault().student.Add(studentModel);
```

This place always happening : **System.IndexOutOfRangeException**

I already change the Paralle.Foreach to Parallel.For , and change the foreach to for, but there is nothing changed.
I must use Parallel because the students count about 100000, if I just use foreach replace Parallel.Foreach, it will take 160+ second,  If I lock that place.....still slow......if use Parallel.Foreach, it will use 20 second around, but I can't handle the exception.

I already try use this replace it:

```
StudentNames name = STUDENT_NAMES.Where(x => x.SearchWords == tempWords).FirstOrDefault();
if (null != name)
   name.student.Add(StudentModel);
```

But the problem still happening on some times........
if I just try...catch it and ignore it, then When I later access the STUDENT_NAMES list , it still throw that exception............

I also try use **ConcurrentBag<>** , but the speed very slow....I can't take it.....

Is there any good way to handle it please. Thank you very much!

**UPDATE:**

What I can't understand is: Why I can't add some thing to the list in the Parallel.Foreach. I think Parallel.Foreach will use a lot thread , but event use multiple thread add is not any problem with it.

thread 1 add and thread 2 add not any relationship.... Why there is happening that exception?

Comment: `I also try use ConcurrentBag<> , but the speed very slow....I can't take it` Then write something better than *ConcurrentBag* that can synchronize the access.

Comment: Not sure what you are tying to do but there has to be something more efficient than that STUDENT_NAMES.Where(x => x.SearchWords == tempWords).FirstOrDefault().  Use a hashset.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`List` is not designed to be accessed from multiple threads.  it is not safe to do so.  You can run into all sorts of problems, ranging from out of index exceptions, additions being lost, duplicated, other types of errors, really just about anything.

> I also try use ConcurrentBag<> , but the speed very slow....I can't take it.....

Performance is irrelevant when only one of the two options actually works.  You can have code that works correctly and takes as long as that takes, or you can have code that doesn't work, and to which how fast it does the wrong this is irrelevant.

Of course you have other options, such as looking at ways of redesigning your program to use an inherently more effective algorithm instead of trying to do something really inefficient and just parallelism it to hide that fact.  The fact that you're currently performing a liner search on your list to find a matching item *for each item in another collection* is a rather poor design; you should use a collection that can be more efficiently searched, such as a `HashSet`.  Without knowing the details of the problem though, we couldn't possibly say what the proper design of the application should be.

Comment: every one, if you has XX.Add() on Parallel.Foreach, you just need change the XX type to hashset from list. the problem will be resolved. thank you @Servy.

Comment: @qakmak No, it most certainly is *not* resolved.  `HashSet` is not at all designed to be manipulated from multiple threads at the same time, and doing so can cause all sorts of nasty behavior, just like with `List`.  That you didn't notice problems in a few test doesn't mean that there weren't any, and even if there weren't any it doesn't mean that there won't be any in the future.

Comment: I think before happening index problem because list use index sort, then when some thread add some object also another thread add some object too, but HasSet not use index sort, So I think problem resolved. because I just need add object to HasSet use Parallel.Foreach, that's all.

Comment: @qakmak That is entirely incorrect.  A `HashSet` is not a all safe to be used in a multithreaded environment without proper synchronization.  Your explanation is entirely incorrect.  Neither data structure is doing any sorting, both data structures are accessing items in a backing array through indexes, they're just doing so in a slightly different manor.  Once again, the code is not safe.  That you haven't noticed an error yet doesn't mean there are none, and it doesn't mean there won't be any.

Comment: You right, still some times has index out of problem. So how do I need to do ??

Comment: @qakmak I explain that to you in my answer.  Perhaps you want to take the time to read it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57034/discussion-between-qakmak-and-servy).